# Javascript print some characters after regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

Input string is "F000668A - EED14F50 - 000EED1KFF0000000F03".

I want to print/save 4 characters after EED1. The number of EED1 can 1 or more.
In the above example, the expected result is => 4F50,KFF0.

My code:

```
var input = "F000668A - EED14F50 - 000EED1kFF0000000F03"

const string = input.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");    //Lowercase it, delete spaces and linebreaks.

string.match(/eed1/g).forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element)
 });
```

Result:

```
eed1
eed1
```

But when I try to print further characters then the script print only 1 item.

```
string.match(/eed1(.*)/g)
```

Result:

```
eed14f50-000eed1kff0000000f03
```

How can I get the requested info with regex? (or an other way)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Capture 4 characters in a group `EED1(\w{4})` https://regex101.com/r/8FMP85/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const input = "F000668A - EED14F50 - 000EED1kFF0000000F03";
const matches = input.replace(/\s/g, '').matchAll(/eed1([a-z0-9]{4})/ig);
console.log(Array.from(matches, m => m[1]));
```

Note:

- You do not need to replace line breaks separately from other whitespaces, `\s` matches `\n`, `\r`, and the rest of vertical whitesapce
- There is no need to lowercase the input, you can use `/i` flag to match in a case insensitive way
- `/eed1([a-z0-9]{4})/ig` will match all occurrences of `eed1` (case insensitively) and then capture four letters/digits, and `matchAll` will ensure the access to all the capturing group values (`match()` discarded them all as the regex was built with the `g` flag).

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CsXbIq/1).

Comment: Thank you. One more question. How can I search for an other regex. How can I concatenate more regex? eg.: EED1(\w{4}) & 0F0

Comment: @Dani Please provide an input string and requirements and expected output. If you need to use a variable in regex, see [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression).